# pywinauto and listitem selection

Tags: automation, pywinauto

I'm playing around with pywinauto and using it to automate Skype functions on Windows 7.

I'm having trouble selecting people from my contact list accurately.

The general code to open Skype and recognize the main window that I'm using is the following:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend= "uia")
app.start('skype.exe')
app.connect(process =1636) # I have this just incase Skype is already open, slightly hacky I suppose
app.SkypeUsername.draw_outline()
dlg =app.SkypeUsername
contacts =dlg.Listbox  # My contacts seem to be under the header "Listbox" when I use point_control identifiers, so I assigned it to contacts for easy reference.
```

I then use point_control_identifiers to see how my contacts are stored.

```
contacts.print_control_identifiers()
Control Identifiers:

ListBox - 'Contacts'    (L-32000, T-31705, R-30080, B-31039)
[u'ContactsListBox', u'Contacts', u'ListBox']
child_window(title="Contacts", control_type="List")
   | 
   | Custom - 'Favorites'    (L-32000, T-31825, R-30095, B-31765)
   | [u'FavoritesCustom', 'Custom', u'Favorites']
   | child_window(title="Favorites", control_type="Custom")
   | 
   | ListItem - 'sayaku o, sayaku353143, Away, Favorite'    (L-32000, T-31705, R-30095, B-31690)
   | [u'sayaku o, sayaku353143, Away, FavoriteListItem', u'ListItem', u'ListItem0', u'ListItem1', u'sayaku o, sayaku353143, Away, Favorite']
   | child_window(title="sayaku o, sayaku353143, Away, Favorite", control_type="ListItem")
   | 
   | ListItem - 'bobby jackson, bjackson01, Offline, Favorite'    (L-32000, T-31690, R-30095, B-31615)
   | [u'ListItem2', u'bobby jackson, bjackson01, Offline, FavoriteListItem', u'bobby jackson, bjackson01, Offline, Favorite']
   | child_window(title="bobby jackson, bjackson01, Offline, Favorite", control_type="ListItem")
   | 
   | ListItem - 'kay_katayama, kay_katayama, Away, Favorite'    (L-32000, T-31615, R-30095, B-31540)
   | [u'ListItem3', u'kay_katayama, kay_katayama, Away, Favorite', u'kay_katayama, kay_katayama, Away, FavoriteListItem']
   | child_window(title="kay_katayama, kay_katayama, Away, Favorite", control_ty
```

To select different contact members, I was creating code like this:

```
sayaku = contacts.ListItem.wrapper_object()
Bobby = contacts.ListItem2.wrapper_object()
```

The problem I noticed with this is that, if I scroll down a little on the contacts list (as in "Bobby" isn't visible under contacts anymore due to me scrolling down), ListItem2 will connect with someone besides Bobby.

So when I use the following code,

```
Bobby.double_click_input()
app.Bobby.wait('visible')
Bobby_box = app.Bobby
Bobby_box.call.click()
```

It was clicking on another contact, and opening the chat window of another contact.

I don't if it's possible to avoid this by selecting the contact by using their name instead of the label 'Listitem2'. However, the labels given are pretty long and have spaces, so I didn't know how to select via the longer labels such as `'bobby jackson, bjackson01, Offline, FavoriteListItem'`

EDIT: I also noticed that the 'Listitem' label is not reliable as it changes often.

For example:

```
ListItem - 'bobby jackson, bjackson01, Offline'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   | [u'bobby jackson, jacksona01, Offline', u'ListItem18', u'bobbyjackson,  bjackson01, OfflineListItem']
   | child_window(title="jackson, bjackson01, Offline", control_type="ListItem")
```

is now `Listitem18`.

I tried calling the list item by `bobby_jackson`  but the window was not being identified. How can I call `'bobby jackson, jacksona01, Offline'`without resorting to `Listitem`?

Thanks.

EDIT:2

Tried the below suggestion via the following code and similar variations, yet still getting errors:

```
 x = contacts.child_window(title="sayaku o, sayaku353143, Away", control_type="ListItem")

x.wrapper_object().click()
```

ElementNotFoundError: {'control_type': 'ListItem', 'title': 'sayaku o, sayaku353143, Away', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': , 'backend': u'uia'}

`contacts.print_control_identifiers()` still prints all the contacts so contacts is being assigned properly.

EDIT 3 (12/19/2016):

I tried the following code as well, and still having trouble selecting the window:

`sayaku =contacts.child_window(title_re='sayaku.*', control_type='ListItem').wrapper_object()`

Comment: Thanks for trying this. This ListBox is a little bit simpler than explorer's list view (items are virtualized and not visible by `Inspect.exe`). So we may miss something very simple while more complicated things work. :) There are several `IsOffscreen=True` items visible in `Inspect.exe`. Will take a look how to fix that.

Comment: Hi, I also edited my question to further illustrate the main problem I'm having. I don't know how to select my contacts when they are being stored as  'sayaku o, sayaku353143, Away, Favorite'. Thanks.

Comment: For stable matching of dynamic texts it's possible to use regular expressions: `.child_window(title_re='sayaku353143.*', control_type='ListItem')`. Sorry, not sure I will have a chance to fix the issue before the New Year, but I will re-check it before 0.6.1 anyway.

Comment: Hi Vasily, I tried your suggestion (using the regular expression and writing out the whole  expression) but I'm still getting the `element not found error`.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong? As for the other issue, no problem. Take your time please. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to add that I had edited the OP to reflect how I tried out your suggestion (I included the code, I 've used). Maybe you will see what mistake I"m making. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... I see you still use `title`, not `title_re`. Please try `title_re` keyword.

Comment: Hi Vasily, I had tried `title_re` as well but when I forgot to include that in my edit. I updated the OP with the `title_re` code I tried (see edit 3 please). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm... Had a chance to try it on my side. `get_item` looks working strange. But `.items()` returns correct list. Will think how to improve `.item(...)/.get_item(...)` usability. At least I know that problem is not in virtualized items. Maybe it's a Unicode<->bytes conversions. Which Python version do you use?

Comment: I'm mainly using Python 2.7. Sometimes I also have trouble connecting to the first dialog of Skype (which has the title Skype - Username). Sometimes I have to run the script a few times to be able to connect to the first dialog. If you want I can send you a video of some of the bugs (or maybe I'm coding incorrectly) that I'm running into. There were a few other things with opening menus that I was having trouble with.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Method connect() has no timeout param yet or default one (we have plans to implement it, but with low priority). We appreciate detailed feedback here or on GitHub (no matter). Big thanks for all the details! If you prefer private thread, please replace dashes ("-") in my GitHub login name with dots (".") and add gmail.com.

Comment: Yeah, I took a couple of videos of the first issue I was having. I will send it to your email because I would rather not have my skype info or contacts being publicly displayed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm back and starting to respond on the feedback. Hope to answer soon. :)

Comment: Okay. Sounds good. Please let me know when you have taken a look at them.